# CSS - Applying the :not() attribute to all wordpress pages except one

Tags: html, css, wordpress, attributes

How do I transform this code

```
.page-id-2 .custom-header-image {
    background: none !important;
    background-color: #ccc !important;
    padding-top: 5%;
    padding-bottom: 5%;
    height: 200px;
}
```

To the exact opposite?

I would like to apply the css to all pages except page-id 2.

This doesn't work of course:

```
:not( .page-id-2 .custom-header-image) {
    background: none !important;
    background-color: #ccc !important;
    padding-top: 5%;
    padding-bottom: 5%;
    height: 200px;
}
```

Have been trying several combinations for the last 30 minutes, no luck.

Comment: It will not work this way, you need to create base styles and apply separate styles for your specific page that will override base styles

Answer (score 2):

You just need to remove the second class from the `:not` argument.

An example, using text instead of image...

```css
.page-id-2 .custom-header-image {
  color: red;
}

:not(.page-id-2) .custom-header-image {
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="page-id-2">
  <p class="custom-header-image">I should <strong>not</strong> be red</p>
</div>
```